# Mapping out Rails Database that includes workers and languages spoken

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am creating something where I want to be able to query workers that can speak a language.

Worker has_many :languages

However, I need to know the fluency they speak and write in the language on a scale of Excellent, Fair, Poor.

What would be a good way to be able to still do "Language.German.workers", for example. But also when I query the Worker I can see the fluency of how they write and speak in them as well. I'm having trouble putting it all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a join table. And you can have a column `fluency` in the join table.

```
class Worker < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :languages, through: :worker_languages
  ...
end

class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workers, through: :worker_languages
  ...
end
class WorkerLanguage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :worker
  belongs_to :language
  ....
 end
```